# Trying to characterize an integer function relation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, diophantine-equations

Let $n$ and $a$ denote positive integers, and let $f_n(a)$ be a monotonically increasing function, with integer coefficients, of degree $n-1$.

If there exists some pair $(n,k)$ such that
$$\frac{(4k+1)f_n(16k+3)}{(8k+1)f_n(16k+2)}=1, \tag{$\star$}$$
is there anything that can be said about $f$ [without knowing its coefficients, *etc.*]?

Evidently $\gcd(4k+1,8k+1)=1$, so we must have $(8k+1) \mid f_n(16k+3)$ and $(4k+1) \mid f_n(16k+2)$; in fact, there must exist a positive integer $m$ such that
$$
f_n(16k+2) = (4k+1)m \qquad\text{and}\qquad f_n(16k+3)=(8k+1)m.
$$
I'm just not sure how to proceed from there.

To be honest, I’ve been trying to find *any* function which satisfies ($\star$) [and the “monotonically increasing integer function” requirements], but haven’t found one yet. I’m close to calling the non-existence of such a function a conjecture, but I’m not quite there yet…

EDIT: @garondal found a counterexample to the [potential] “conjecture“ (see first answer).

Comment: Do you mean by _integer function_ an  integer-valued function or a function with intergers as domain?

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=67x^2-1111x$ and $n-1=2$ and $k=1$. This function is monotonically increasing for $x \geq 1$.

$f(19)=3078$ and $f(18)=1710$. Then you have that $\frac{5f(19)}{9f(18)}=1$.

Unfortunately I found this with brute force so I cannot offer any insights.

Edit for more general case: If you define $$f_n(x)=a_n x^n - a_{n+1} x^{n-1}$$ with $a_1=4$ and $$a_n=a_{n-1}\cdot \dfrac{5\cdot 19^{n-1}-9\cdot 18^{n-1}}{5\cdot 19^{n-2}-9\cdot 18^{n-2}}$$ you get a function with $\frac{5f_n(19)}{9f_n(18)}=1$. The sequence $(a_n)$ is $4, 67, 1111, 18\,193, 29\,3179, \ldots$. This seems to work but the functions are not monotonically increasing for $x\geq 1$.

Comment: Still, I appreciate the counterexample! I‘ve edited my post accordingly. If you find any other counterexamples, please let me know — perhaps we can find a pattern.

Comment: In the puzzle I'm working on, $f_n(1) = 1$ for all $n$, _i.e._ $f_n(a) \ge 1$ for all $a$. It will be interesting to see if we find any counterexample functions which also satisfy that restriction.

Comment: I edited my answer. Maybe this helps you to understand the problem.